# Custom PhaseListener - which phase to terminate a user session

Tags: jsf

I've implemented a custom PhaseListener to terminate the user session in case of a special system condition which is page independent. So, no `f:viewAction` tag is applicable. Now, the question is in which phase do I have to call

```java
request.logout();
session.invalidate();
```

and in `beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)` or in `afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)`?

Mojarra 2.3.14

**UPDATE 02.05.2023**

I've initial choosen a phase listener because I have to open a database connection per page request and in a servlet filter this connection is established multiple times since the filter is called multiple times per page request. The phase listener is called only one time (e.g. phase `PhaseID.RENDER_RESPONSE`). This would be a benefit in my case. How to deal with this problem in servlet filter? Thx.

Comment: Please open a new question and put your update there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of all. In first place, if you already don't know which JSF phase you need to kick in then you most probably don't need a phase listener at all.

Use a normal servlet filter instead.

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = { "Your Faces Servlet Name (as you've declared in web.xml)" })
public class LogoutFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        if (someCondition) {
            request.logout();
            request.getSession().invalidate();
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```